# Travelling to Europe with expired h1b stamp

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airlines, h1b-visas, western-europe

I am working in US on H1b visa. My visa stamp & I94 expired last year but I received my I797, which allows me to work legally in US. I only need the h1b stamping for reentry after leaving the country. I am planning to travel to Portugal (Lisbon) for my H1b stamping and return to US. I have a valid Schengen visa.

Do you think I will face any issues in boarding flight in US or after landing in Portugal because of my expired stamp? I have read stories where the airlines do not let you board a flight because you can't return to US. Ironically, that is exactly why I am travelling in the first place (for my stamping and thus return to US).

Appreciate all your feedback! This is my first post - happy to correct it if it doesn't meet the standard.

Comment: They only care about your destination (and any intermediate layovers). If your case you have 2 journeys: US to Portugal (they check you will be acceptable in Portugal before you get on the plane to Portugal) and then Portugal to US (they check the US should let you in before getting on the plane to US).

Answer (score 1):

The airline will only check your documents relating to your current flight itinerary.

For example, with a return ticket from the US to Portugal, the airline will check that you can enter Portugal when you check in for your flight to Portugal. Your documents for entering the US will be checked when you check in for the return flight to the US.

As for entering the Schengen area, if you have a valid multiple entry Schengen visa and have used it before or it is issued by Portugal, you are unlikely to have problems with immigration.